# Whenever the wind whistles through the leaves, I’ll think, “Lowenstein, Lowenstein"

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is what Marge Simpson, from the Simpsons, says when she leaves the psychiatrist after she is cured in episode 11, season 6.

What does she refer to when she says **Lowenstein**. Is the sentence from a movie scene or line or from a famous poem?

> Whenever the wind whistles through the leaves, I’ll think,
>   “Lowenstein, Lowenstein".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgTtgVC0G8A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a reference to a movie, *Prince of Tides*, which ends with the narrator speaking about the psychiatrist Susan Lowenstein, with whom he has had both a professional and a romantic relationship:

> At the end of every day I drive through the city of Charleston and I cross the bridge that will take me home. I feel the words building inside me, I can't stop them, or tell you why I say them, but as I reach the top of the bridge these words come to me in a whisper. I say these words as a prayer, as regret, as praise, I say: Lowenstein, Lowenstein.